# Re-use http connection Python 3

Tags: python, sockets, http, tcp, urllib

So every second I am making a bunch of requests to website X every second, as of now with the standard `urllib` packages like so (the requestreturns a json):

```
import urllib.request
import threading, time

def makerequests():
    request = urllib.request.Request('http://www.X.com/Y')
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=makerequests)
    t.start()
```

However because I'm making so much requests after about 500 requests the website returns `HTTPError 429: Too manyrequests`. I was thinking it might help if I re-use the initial TCP connection, however I noticed it was not possible to do this with the `urllib` packages.

So I did some googling and discovered that the following packages might help:

- `Requests`
- `http.client`
- `socket` ?

So I have a question: which one is best suited for my situation and can someone show an example of either one of them (for Python 3)?

Comment: To answer your question `requests` is (probably) the best - it handles keep alive automatically. What might actually help though is to make fewer requests.

Comment: If the website is rate limiting requests, then re-using the tcp connection probably won't work.

Comment: I assume the sysadmin of the web site knows what your are doing and why. If not looping repeatedly same request could be seen as an attack and you IP will end in a black list.

Answer (score 2):

`requests` handles [keep alive](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive) automatically if you use a session. This might not actually help you if the server is rate limiting requests, however, `requests` also handles parsing JSON so that's a good reason to use it. Here's an example:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    response = s.get('http://www.X.com/y')
    data = response.json()
```